# Typescript CompilerAPI: how to get "expanded" type AST

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

The types in my application are defined in a somewhat convoluted way: I define algebra on functions, construct the "decoder" functions and then infer types from a decoder (see gcanti/io-fp).
There's an issue reported to typedoc project [#1519](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1519).

Now I want to write an utility to generate proper .d.ts documentation for my API so that the output:

```js
export declare type BorderStyleEnum = 'None' | 'Solid';
export declare type BorderStyle = {
    Color?: string;
    Style?: BorderStyleEnum;
    Width?: string;
};
export declare type BorderSideStyle = {
    Color?: string;
    Style?: '' | 'None' | 'Solid';
    Width?: string;
};
export declare type BorderSideStyleEnum = NonNullable<BorderSideStyle['Style']>;
export declare type Style = { Border: BorderStyle; TopBorder: BorderSideStyle; LeftBorder: BorderSideStyle; BottomBorder: BorderSideStyle; RightBorder: BorderSideStyle;
};
export declare type StyleExp = ExpandRecursively<Style>;
declare function item(): {
    /** type of the element */
    type: 'item';
    name: string;
    style: Style;
};
export declare type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K];
} : never;
export declare type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object ? T extends infer O ? {
    [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]>;
} : never : T;
export declare type Item = ExpandRecursively<ReturnType<typeof item>>;
export {};
```

becomes more compact like this (I made it manually)

```js
export type BorderStyleEnum = "None" | "Solid";
export type BorderStyle = { Color?: string; Style?: BorderStyleEnum; Width?: string; };
export type BorderSideStyle = { Color?: string; Style?: BorderSideStyleEnum; Width?: string; };
export type BorderSideStyleEnum = "" | "None" | "Solid";
export type Style = { Border: BorderStyle; TopBorder: BorderSideStyle; LeftBorder: BorderSideStyle; BottomBorder: BorderSideStyle; RightBorder: BorderSideStyle; };
export type StyleExp = Style;
export type Item = { type: "item"; name: string; style: Style };
```

Currently I'm using the following snippet to get a type definition:

```js
    const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
    const typeDecl = typeChecker.typeToString(type, node,
        ts.TypeFormatFlags.NoTruncation
        // | ts.TypeFormatFlags.MultilineObjectLiterals
        | ts.TypeFormatFlags.InTypeAlias
        // | ts.TypeFormatFlags.UseAliasDefinedOutsideCurrentScope  // prevents type expansion
        // | ts.TypeFormatFlags.UseStructuralFallback
        );
```

It does work quite well and "expands" complicated types such as this: `export type Item = ExpandRecursively<ReturnType<typeof item>>;`.

However my goal is to obtain AST for expanded definition so that I can apply my own "reduction" rules.

The sample code is available at https://replit.com/@OlegZaimkin/KhakiBrokenPagerecognition#index.ts.

Is there a way to get types evaluated/resolved to the lowest possible level and obtain AST for the result?
Are there other ideas to solve the original problem?

**Answer**:
It looks like `NodeBuilderFlags.InTypeAlias` did the trick. I managed to obtain AST for "expanded" type by adding this flag to `typeToTypeNode`'s `flags` argument:

```js
var rnode = typeChecker.typeToTypeNode(type, undefined,
        ts.NodeBuilderFlags.NoTruncation
        | ts.NodeBuilderFlags.InTypeAlias
        );
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? E.g. how `typeChecker` is set up? And maybe also the typescript version you are using. I tried reproducing your problem with typescript 3.9.7, but successfully got `"" | "None" | "Solid"`.

Comment: @mihi thanks for pointing this `typeToString` works as expected and it returns reduced type. However my goal is to obtain AST so that I will reduce the types further. Can you please see https://replit.com/@OlegZaimkin/KhakiBrokenPagerecognition#index.ts

Comment: Ahh, now I understand what you were trying to achieve. Doing some digging I also just found `typeChecker.typeToTypeNode` and was about to comment, but I see you figured that out as well :)